# Constructing XML-Like Mark-Up in ForEach Loop with PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array

```
[0] => 0101010101-0101010101
[1] => 1212121212-1212121212
[2] => 2323232323-2323232323
[3] => 3434343434-3434343434
```

in a variable defined as `$legacyorderid`

I'm trying to create another variable called `$orderid` which, constructed in my foreach loop, will output like this:

```
<OrderId>0101010101-0101010101</OrderID><OrderId>1212121212-1212121212</OrderID><OrderId>2323232323-2323232323</OrderID><OrderId>3434343434-3434343434</OrderID>
```

I'm using concatenation in my foreach loop, but it's still not working

```
foreach ($legacyorderid as $num => $orderid2) {
    $orderid .= '<OrderID>' . $orderid2 . '</OrderID>';
}
```

All this is outputting in an `echo` of `orderid` is:

```
0101010101-01010101011212121212-12121212122323232323-23232323233434343434-3434343434
```

How do I get my `<OrderID>` and `</OrderID>` into my `$orderid` variable like the desired output above?

Comment: Your viewing the file as HTML, not XML...  If you open inspect, you will see the tags.

Comment: You are correct :) Did not realize that, thought I was doing some astray. Thank you.

Comment: Sure.  9 Minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're viewing the file as HTML, not XML...  If you open inspect/view source, you will see the tags.